# In Flutter, horizontal scroll bar not showing in Data Table

Tags: flutter, datatable

I am using `DataTable` with both vertical and horizontal `scrollbar`. The vertical scrollbar indicator is showing, but the horizontal scrollbar indicator down does not shows. Here is my code:

```dart
class NewAppointments extends StatelessWidget {
  const NewAppointments({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: DataTable(
          columns: [
            DataColumn(
              label: Expanded(
                child: Text(
                  'Date',
                  style: fontStyleSemibold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            DataColumn(
              label: Expanded(
                child: Text(
                  'Patient Name',
                  style: fontStyleSemibold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            DataColumn(
              label: Expanded(
                child: Text(
                  'Contact',
                  style: fontStyleSemibold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            DataColumn(
              label: Expanded(
                child: Text(
                  'Doctor',
                  style: fontStyleSemibold,
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
          rows: [
            DataRow(
              cells: [
                DataCell(
                  Text(
                    '12-04-2023',
                    style: fontStyleRegular.copyWith(fontSize: 14),
                    maxLines: 1,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                ),
                DataCell(
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      CircularImage(
                          height: 24,
                          width: 24,
                          imageUrl: 'assests/images/icon_person.png',
                          onClick: () {}),
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 4,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Muhammad Hasnain',
                        style: fontStyleRegular.copyWith(fontSize: 14),
                        maxLines: 1,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                DataCell(
                  Text(
                    '03028983053',
                    style: fontStyleRegular.copyWith(fontSize: 14),
                    maxLines: 1,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                ),
                DataCell(
                  Text(
                    'Dr Hasnain',
                    style: fontStyleRegular.copyWith(fontSize: 14),
                    maxLines: 1,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            DataRow(
              cells: [
                DataCell(
                  Text(
                    '12-04-2023',
                    style: fontStyleRegular.copyWith(fontSize: 14),
                    maxLines: 1,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                ),
                DataCell(
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      CircularImage(
                          height: 24,
                          width: 24,
                          imageUrl: 'assests/images/icon_person.png',
                          onClick: () {}),
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 4,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Muhammad Hasnain',
                        style: fontStyleRegular.copyWith(fontSize: 14),
                        maxLines: 1,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                DataCell(
                  Text(
                    '03028983053',
                    style: fontStyleRegular.copyWith(fontSize: 14),
                    maxLines: 1,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                ),
                DataCell(
                  Text(
                    'Dr Hasnain',
                    style: fontStyleRegular.copyWith(fontSize: 14),
                    maxLines: 1,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            DataRow(
              cells: [
                DataCell(
                  Text(
                    '12-04-2023',
                    style: fontStyleRegular.copyWith(fontSize: 14),
                    maxLines: 1,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                ),
                DataCell(
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      CircularImage(
                          height: 24,
                          width: 24,
                          imageUrl: 'assests/images/icon_person.png',
                          onClick: () {}),
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 4,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Muhammad Hasnain',
                        style: fontStyleRegular.copyWith(fontSize: 14),
                        maxLines: 1,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                DataCell(
                  Text(
                    '03028983053',
                    style: fontStyleRegular.copyWith(fontSize: 14),
                    maxLines: 1,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                ),
                DataCell(
                  Text(
                    'Dr Hasnain',
                    maxLines: 1,
                    style: fontStyleRegular.copyWith(fontSize: 14),
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            DataRow(
              cells: [
                DataCell(
                  Text(
                    '12-04-2023',
                    style: fontStyleRegular.copyWith(fontSize: 14),
                    maxLines: 1,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                ),
                DataCell(
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      CircularImage(
                          height: 24,
                          width: 24,
                          imageUrl: 'assests/images/icon_person.png',
                          onClick: () {}),
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 4,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Muhammad Hasnain',
                        style: fontStyleRegular.copyWith(fontSize: 14),
                        maxLines: 1,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                DataCell(
                  Text(
                    '03028983053',
                    style: fontStyleRegular.copyWith(fontSize: 14),
                    maxLines: 1,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                ),
                DataCell(
                  Text(
                    'Dr Hasnain',
                    style: fontStyleRegular.copyWith(fontSize: 14),
                    maxLines: 1,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            DataRow(
              cells: [
                DataCell(
                  Text(
                    '12-04-2023',
                    style: fontStyleRegular.copyWith(fontSize: 14),
                    maxLines: 1,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                ),
                DataCell(
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      CircularImage(
                          height: 24,
                          width: 24,
                          imageUrl: 'assests/images/icon_person.png',
                          onClick: () {}),
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 4,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Muhammad Hasnain',
                        style: fontStyleRegular.copyWith(fontSize: 14),
                        maxLines: 1,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                DataCell(
                  Text(
                    '03028983053',
                    style: fontStyleRegular.copyWith(fontSize: 14),
                    maxLines: 1,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                ),
                DataCell(
                  Text(
                    'Dr Hasnain',
                    style: fontStyleRegular.copyWith(fontSize: 14),
                    maxLines: 1,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            DataRow(
              cells: [
                DataCell(
                  Text(
                    '12-04-2023',
                    style: fontStyleRegular.copyWith(fontSize: 14),
                    maxLines: 1,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                ),
                DataCell(
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      CircularImage(
                          height: 24,
                          width: 24,
                          imageUrl: 'assests/images/icon_person.png',
                          onClick: () {}),
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 4,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Muhammad Hasnain',
                        style: fontStyleRegular.copyWith(fontSize: 14),
                        maxLines: 1,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                DataCell(
                  Text(
                    '03028983053',
                    style: fontStyleRegular.copyWith(fontSize: 14),
                    maxLines: 1,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                ),
                DataCell(
                  Text(
                    'Dr Hasnain',
                    style: fontStyleRegular.copyWith(fontSize: 14),
                    maxLines: 1,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            DataRow(
              cells: [
                DataCell(
                  Text(
                    '12-04-2023',
                    style: fontStyleRegular.copyWith(fontSize: 14),
                    maxLines: 1,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                ),
                DataCell(
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      CircularImage(
                          height: 24,
                          width: 24,
                          imageUrl: 'assests/images/icon_person.png',
                          onClick: () {}),
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 4,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Muhammad Hasnain',
                        style: fontStyleRegular.copyWith(fontSize: 14),
                        maxLines: 1,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                DataCell(
                  Text(
                    '03028983053',
                    maxLines: 1,
                    style: fontStyleRegular.copyWith(fontSize: 14),
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                ),
                DataCell(
                  Text(
                    'Dr Hasnain',
                    style: fontStyleRegular.copyWith(fontSize: 14),
                    maxLines: 1,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            DataRow(
              cells: [
                DataCell(
                  Text(
                    '12-04-2023',
                    style: fontStyleRegular.copyWith(fontSize: 14),
                    maxLines: 1,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                ),
                DataCell(
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      CircularImage(
                          height: 24,
                          width: 24,
                          imageUrl: 'assests/images/icon_person.png',
                          onClick: () {}),
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 4,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Muhammad Hasnain',
                        style: fontStyleRegular.copyWith(fontSize: 14),
                        maxLines: 1,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                DataCell(
                  Text(
                    '03028983053',
                    style: fontStyleRegular.copyWith(fontSize: 14),
                    maxLines: 1,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                ),
                DataCell(
                  Text(
                    'Dr Hasnain',
                    style: fontStyleRegular.copyWith(fontSize: 14),
                    maxLines: 1,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72734055/10885244 This answer have solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use [adaptive_scrollbar](https://pub.dev/packages/adaptive_scrollbar#multiple-scrollbars) package. It will show multiple scrollbars

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your ScrollView with a ScrolBar and give the direction you want to show the scrolll bar.

```dart
ScrollBar(
    scrollbarOrientation: ScrollbarOrientation.bottom,
)
```

Comment: It only shows horizontal bar when I scroll horizontally at the end then scroll down vertically then it shows vertical var I want to show bot horizontal and vertical bars at the same time

Comment: add `thumbVisibility:true` parameter in both scroll bar

Answer (score 0):

Try this demo :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class horizontalScroll extends StatefulWidget {
  const horizontalScroll({super.key});

  @override
  State<horizontalScroll> createState() => _horizontalScrollState();
}

class _horizontalScrollState extends State<horizontalScroll> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: DataTable(
          columns: [
            DataColumn(label: Text('Column 1')),
            DataColumn(label: Text('Column 2')),
            DataColumn(label: Text('Column 3')),
            DataColumn(label: Text('Column 1')),
            DataColumn(label: Text('Column 2')),
            DataColumn(label: Text('Column 3')),
          ],
          rows: [
            DataRow(cells: [
              DataCell(Text('Cell 1')),
              DataCell(Text('Cell 2')),
              DataCell(Text('Cell 3')),
              DataCell(Text('Cell 1')),
              DataCell(Text('Cell 2')),
              DataCell(Text('Cell 3')),
            ]),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```